# Python 3 memory error for large loop with large sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, memory, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am working with a code that involves the creating of a large relatively sparse matrix and the solution of a least squares minimization problem using it. However, I have been getting memory errors when I run my code, despite the fact that it seems that the matrix should not be large enough to strain my system (27000 by 2100 roughly, in my test cases)

I have created a simplified code that has the same storage requirements as my test case and also generates a memory error (note that the "sparse" matrix is not actually very sparse as I am testing with a smaller scale problem than what the actual intended dataset will entail):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

BM = sparse.lil_matrix((27000, 3000))
for i in range(0, 3000):
    local_mat = np.random.rand(30,30,30)
    local_mat[local_mat<0.1] = 0
    vals = local_mat.ravel()
    nonzero = vals.nonzero()
    BM[nonzero, i] = vals[nonzero]
```

If I change the parameters such that there are more zero entries in the sparse matrix, I will still get a memory error from scipy.sparse.linalg.lsq_linear after filling the rows of the matrix and performing a minimization problem with it

It goes without saying that I get a memory error if I use a dense matrix as well.

I have tried to increase the size of my paging file to 2-4 gigabytes but that hasn't helped, though it seems like this should not be that memory intensive regardless

Comment: When I loop 30 times, `BM.nnz` is 729012.  The last iteration has set 24182 of possible 27000 elements..  This is not sparse at all!

Comment: Yes that's more or less a quirk of the specific test case i'm using, since the code is oriented around particle measurements in 3d space, but I've been using 30x30x30 densely packed windows before moving on to large 1000x1000x100 data sets.

Comment: I don't want to intentionally create a memory error or otherwise hang my computer.  You'll have to sort out these issues yourself.  Keep a watch on the matrix sparsity, and watch out for any inadvertent conversion to dense.  If the memory error produces a traceback, examine that,and maybe even post it.

Comment: Alright. In general, do you know of any alternative solutions? Even calling an operation like nonzero() on the dense version of the matrix causes a memory error

Comment: A useful sparse matrix will be 90% zeros (or higher)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a memory bonfire. Let's recall how a `lil_matrix` works:

Each row of the matrix is kept as a **python** list. There is one list for data and another list for index. Each non-zero element has one entry on each list.

Taking your example `27000, 3000` matrix, let's add this up. Each entry in a python list is an object which burns 16 bytes for overhead. For the data list, the float data itself is another 8 bytes. So just the non-zero values eats up 2GB. Now let's look at the indices - another set of lists each entry of which burns 16 bytes for overhead. Poof - there's another 1.5 GB gone. Bit more memory for the lists and the array that holds them, but that's not much compared to what's already gone down.

Compared to a `27000, 3000` dense array, which eats up 650MB of memory, you've managed to use an extra 5x as much memory, while also acquiring several *major* disadvantages compared to a numpy array. A standard sparse format like `CSR` would be a much better choice - that would use just about 900MB of memory for your 90% dense example.

EDIT: Also you're trying to call a function which absolutely requires a `CSR` matrix, so that function is casting the horrible `lil_matrix` you've created into a `csr_matrix`, forcing you to keep two full copies of this data in-memory.

Comment: I assume he's using `lil` because he's building the matrix iteratively, block by block.  `csr` objects to setting nonzero values,   The time honored method is to construct the `coo` style inputs iteratively, and create the matrix from that with one call.  The `bmat` (and `hstack` and `vstack`) functions do that.

Comment: This was enlightening, thank you for the answers. Regarding the density of the matrix:  that's more or less a quirk of the specific test case i'm using, since the code is oriented around particle measurements in 3d space, but I've been using 30x30x30 densely packed windows (with Np = 2100 particles) before moving on to large 1000x1000x100 data sets. \\

Consequently though, I have to construct this matrix as sparse from the ground-up, so I was wondering if there was a way to do so efficiently with csr matrices. Otherwise I may have to implement a "sliding window" type approach

Comment: The most efficient easy way to column-wise build a CSR matrix is probably to `hstack` a list of `CSC` or `COO` matrices which each represent a single column. The absolute most memory-efficient way is two-pass; run through the problem once to figure out how much memory you need to allocate, allocate that memory, and then run through the problem again to populate the allocated memory with values. You won't need any intermediate data structures that way.

Comment: Thank you. What is the best way to preallocate? I tried to simply hstack a list of Nx1 csc matrices but I run into problems when hstacking

Comment: Also if I increase the "size" of the array to 100000 by ... instead of 27000 by ... I will run into memory errors in the former case but not in the latter, but I am keeping the number of nonzero entries the same

Comment: I think it would be better for you to make a new question about the actual problem that you've got (what you're trying to calculate and how) instead of a question about the consequences of the solution you're trying to implement.

Comment: Ok, for now I will mark your answer as accepted for anyone searching this for some notes on sparse matrices