# How to get indices of lil_matrix elements in a for loop?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I created a sparse matrix using `scipy.sparse.lil_matrix`:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
test = sp.lil_matrix((3,3))
test[0,0]=1
```

I can loop over and print the nonzero elements by doing:

```
for el in test:
    print(el)
```

which prints out `(0, 0)    1.0`. How do I access these two pieces of information without printing? In other words, what are the appropriate methods for the elements of `lil_matrix` that return indices and value? Doing `el.data` returns `array([list([])], dtype=object)`.

Note that I'm using `lil_matrix` because I will need to assign nonzero values to it within a very large, double for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display you seek is a lot like the `str` display of a `coo` sparse matrix.

```
In [216]: M = (sparse.random(5,5,.2)*10).astype(int)
In [217]: M
Out[217]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [218]: print(M)   # str(M)
  (0, 0)    0
  (0, 2)    8
  (1, 3)    8
  (1, 4)    8
  (4, 4)    4
```

Sparse matrices have a `nonzero` method to show the coordinates of nonzero elements.

```
In [219]: M.nonzero()
Out[219]: (array([0, 1, 1, 4], dtype=int32), array([2, 3, 4, 4], dtype=int32))
```

For `coo`, values are stored as 3 arrays:

```
In [220]: M.data, M.row, M.col
Out[220]: 
(array([0, 8, 8, 8, 4]),
 array([0, 0, 1, 1, 4], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 2, 3, 4, 4], dtype=int32))
```

There are no constraints on the order of these elements in the `coo` format.  There can even be duplicates, though those are summed when convert to display or `csr` format.

When we convert this to `lil` format, the data is now stored in 2 arrays of lists, one list per row:

```
In [221]: Ml = M.tolil()
In [222]: Ml.data
Out[222]: 
array([list([0, 8]), list([8, 8]), list([]), list([]), list([4])],
      dtype=object)
In [223]: Ml.rows
Out[223]: 
array([list([0, 2]), list([3, 4]), list([]), list([]), list([4])],
      dtype=object)
```

It too has the `nonzero`, but look at the code (it uses the `coo` format):

```
In [224]: Ml.nonzero()
Out[224]: (array([0, 1, 1, 4], dtype=int32), array([2, 3, 4, 4], dtype=int32))
In [225]: Ml.nonzero??
Signature: Ml.nonzero()
Source:   
    def nonzero(self):
         ...
        # convert to COOrdinate format
        A = self.tocoo()
        nz_mask = A.data != 0
        return (A.row[nz_mask], A.col[nz_mask])
File:      /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py
Type:      method
```

Actually that's the generic `nonzero` for all sparse formats.  The `nz_mask` part allows for the fact that the matrix might have 0 values that haven't been cleaned up.

While `lil` is designed for easy update element by element, we usually recommend creating a matrix from `coo` style of input arrays if possible.  It's usually possible to create those arrays more efficiently.  Even list appends or extend can be faster.

Looking more at iteration on the `Ml` matrix - it creates a `lil` for each row:

```
In [230]: [x for x in Ml]
Out[230]: 
[<1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in List of Lists format>,
 <1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in List of Lists format>,
 <1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in List of Lists format>,
 <1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in List of Lists format>,
 <1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in List of Lists format>]
```

We could show the data for each row:

```
In [231]: [((i,x.rows[0]),x.data[0]) for i,x in enumerate(Ml)]
Out[231]: 
[((0, [0, 2]), [0, 8]),
 ((1, [3, 4]), [8, 8]),
 ((2, []), []),
 ((3, []), []),
 ((4, [4]), [4])]
```

or filtering out the empty rows:

```
In [232]: [((i,x.rows[0]),x.data[0]) for i,x in enumerate(Ml) if x.data[0]]
Out[232]: [((0, [0, 2]), [0, 8]), ((1, [3, 4]), [8, 8]), ((4, [4]), [4])]
```

We'd need another iteration to separate out elements in each row.

On the use of sparse versus dense arrays, a rule of thumb is that the sparsity (% of nonzero elements) should be less that 10% for it to be worth using a sparse format.  But that depends a lot on your use and concern.

From a simple data storage view point, note that the `coo` format has to use 3 numbers for each nonzero term, as opposed to just 1 for the dense array.  Sparse matrix multiplication is relatively good for the `csr` format.  Other calculations that can focus just on the `data` values (e.g. `sin`) are also relatively efficient.  But if the math has to compare the sparsity of 2 matrices, such as addition and element-wise multiplication, sparse fare worse.

Indexing, slicing, and summation may actually use matrix multiplication.  `coo` format doesn't implement those. `lil` can do some row oriented operations well.  And the basic act of creating a sparse matrix takes time.

Answer (score 1):

It's all in `.data` and `.rows`

```
from scipy import sparse
arr = sparse.random(10,5,format='lil', density=0.5)
```

For this 10x5 array with 25 elements:

```
>>> arr
<10x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 25 stored elements in List of Lists format>

>>> arr.data.shape
(10,)

>>> arr.data
array([list([0.7656088763162588, 0.7262695483137545]),
       list([0.5229054168281109, 0.6329489698531673, 0.9090750679268123]),
       list([0.3285250285217297, 0.12678874412598085, 0.49074613569184733]),
       list([0.9376762935882884]), list([0.7783159122917774]),
       list([0.8750078624527947, 0.017065437987856757, 0.7161352157970525]),
       list([0.6849637433019786, 0.05732598765212671, 0.09948536587262824]),
       list([0.5683250727980487, 0.960851197599538, 0.7540173942047833]),
       list([0.5891879469424754, 0.7901005027272154, 0.5829700379167293]),
       list([0.6266097436787399, 0.8843420498719459, 0.9040791506861361])],
      dtype=object)
```

Each element of the `.data` array is a list that has the values for that row.

```
>>> arr.rows
array([list([0, 4]), list([0, 1, 4]), list([1, 3, 4]), list([1]),
       list([3]), list([0, 1, 2]), list([0, 1, 4]), list([1, 2, 3]),
       list([0, 2, 4]), list([0, 1, 3])], dtype=object)
```

Each element of the `.rows` array is a list of the column indices of each non-zero value in `.data`.

> Note that I'm using lil_matrix because I will need to assign nonzero values to it within a very large, double for loop.

This is almost certainly not a good idea. The overhead for the `lil_matrix` means that if it's not less than 5% sparse you're almost certainly better off filling a dense array. Even then it's pretty iffy. This is a very bad data storage format.

EDIT:

```
>>>> for r in arr:
>>>>     print(r.data)

[list([0.7656088763162588, 0.7262695483137545])]
[list([0.5229054168281109, 0.6329489698531673, 0.9090750679268123])]
[list([0.3285250285217297, 0.12678874412598085, 0.49074613569184733])]
[list([0.9376762935882884])]
[list([0.7783159122917774])]
[list([0.8750078624527947, 0.017065437987856757, 0.7161352157970525])]
[list([0.6849637433019786, 0.05732598765212671, 0.09948536587262824])]
[list([0.5683250727980487, 0.960851197599538, 0.7540173942047833])]
[list([0.5891879469424754, 0.7901005027272154, 0.5829700379167293])]
[list([0.6266097436787399, 0.8843420498719459, 0.9040791506861361])]
```

EDIT 2:

I don't know what your actual functions or goals are but if you know how many non-zero items you have you could preallocate the arrays you need and skip the entire lil thing.

```
import numpy as np

N = 10000
data, rows, cols = np.zeros(N), np.zeros(N), np.zeros(N)

for i, r in enumerate(_):
    for j, c in enumerate(_):
        _idx = i * len(cols) + j
        data[_idx] = some_data_function()
        rows[_idx] = r
        cols[_idx] = c

arr = sparse.csr_matrix((data, (rows, cols)))
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this but I was hoping to be able to get this info from individual elements. I thought, because `print()` can get that info, maybe there's a way to do that as well. If not, I'll revert back to this scheme.

Comment: You can loop through the matrix and it'll give you a ***copy*** of each row (which will have the same `.data` and `.rows` elements that you can work with for that row. Wrapping the loop in enumerate gives you the row index.

Comment: I'm fine with copies, but `.rows` and `.data` returns empty lists.

Comment: They'll only do that if there's no element in that row. Otherwise it'll give you the values in the row.

Comment: Oh, okay, my bad, I was looking at the last row only, which is empty. I see it now.

Comment: For your comment about the data format: a dense matrix would be N by N, but I have O(N) nonzero elements. Is it still bad? If so, what other structure could I consider?

Comment: Basically any other data structure would be better. It's hard to find something worse than `lil`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62154707/7340948